# Gson: Parsing String[]

Tags: json, parsing, gson

I'm using Gson library to parse JSON objects. In particular, I've got a JSON like this:

```
{
 "key": ["string1", "string2"]
}
```

and I would like to parse it in a simple String[], without building a specific object. I tried this way:

```
gson.fromJson(json, String[].class);
```

but I had an error: "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY", I guess because of the presence of the key. Any ideas how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class that has a `key` property that has type of `String[]` and deserialize to that.

```
public class Thing
{
    private String[] key;

    public String[] getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}

Thing thing = gson.fromJson(json, Thing.class);
```

Comment: I've thought about this, but I was trying to avoid creating a new class since I just need a simple String[]. Is it possible?

Comment: @Heisenberg you could modify the json string before doing deserialization, but really I think you should just deserialize the data into a type that it represents. If the class really bothers you then maybe create a wrapper around `gson`, deserialize to an inner class, and return the `String[]` contained in it.

Comment: No, it's not a big problem creating a new class, but I was wondering if there was a more immediate way of doing that. If there isn't a smarter solution I will create that class...

Answer (score 1):

Since **tvanfosson** answer is perfect, I should not  add anything but in the comment you asked is it's possible to avoid creating the `Thing` class. Yes, it is but I think is more fragile. I'm going to show you how to do with this code:

```
    String json = "{\"key\": [\"string1\", \"string2\"]}";
    String mJson = json.replace("{\"key\":", "").replace("}","");
    String[] strings = new Gson().fromJson(mJson, String[].class);
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(strings));
```

Of course this code runs without errors and avoids you additional classes, but think to what happens if there's some carriage return inside. **It breaks**, unless you user a regexp inside the replace invocation. At this point I prefer to add a class instead of thinking of right regexp and let Gson do the whole work.

I added this as response and not as comment to have enough space to explain myself, but this answer should not be taken as right response but instead as poor hack to use. It pays better to understand a bit more how Gson reasons.